# XPage - Save property file from JavaBean

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-extlib

After some tries and a lot of Google-ing I ended up asking again =)

I have a Java Bean that creates a `TreeSet<String>` containing some users for my database to work with. Because it takes some time to create my `TreeSet` I want to save it to a `properties`file.

Getting / reading the property file in my Bean was no problem, also setting a Property is easy but how can I create a `OutputStream` to my resource?

Code snippet:

```
try {
    Properties userproperties;
    userproperties = new Properties();
    userproperties.load(FacesContextEx.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/user.properties"));

    for (String groupmember : groupmembers) {
        userproperties.setProperty("UserList", groupmember);
    }
    // userproperties.save(OutputStream, comments)

} catch (Exception e) {
    // some errorhandling
}
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the `OutputStream` using "user.properties" or with `getRealPath()` this way? http://www.coderanch.com/t/358508/Servlets/java/write-Property-file-Run-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via a DXL Import. Create a DXL file on your filesystem and import it into the database.

Note that webusers must have at least designer rights (advanced ACL settings)

But it seems there is a bug with 8.5.2, I couldn't get it to work with this version.

Comment: Thanks for the Idea but i dont want to touch the filesystem of the Server. I hoped for a solution wich lets me create a OutputStream to my `WebContent/WEB-INF/user.properties` file in my Database. Like i got the InputStream from `getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: @MichaelSaiz: It is not required to create a DXL file, you can do this on-the-fly (from a String, a NotesStream, a RichTextItem).

Comment: @MichaelSaiz I believe Matthias and Sven are talking about File Resource design element which you could use instead of WEB-INF/.

Comment: OK, sounds interesting and how can i create a File Resource design element with the DXL Exporter? Every example i find just points to a location on the filesystem.

Comment: Basically you do a normal DXL Import, the type is defined via a flag in the DXL, for file ressources it is <item name='$Flags'><text>345CgQ</text></item> You create a stream object, create the DXL and then import it. With thr right flag the object is cvreated as file ressource. My DXL looks something like this:

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<fileresource name='' noreplace='false' publicaccess='false' designerversion='8.5.3'>
 <filedata>" + content (BASE64) + "</filedata>
  <item name='$FileSize' sign='true'>
   <numberlist
    <number>filesize</number>
   </numberlist>
  </item>
  <item name='$FileModDT' sign='true'>
   <datetimelist>
    <datetime>sdf.format(dt.toJavaDate()) + "T" + sdf2.format(dt.toJavaDate()) + ",00-00");</datetime>
   </datetimelist>
  </item>
  <item name='$Flags'><text>345CgQ</text></item>
  <item name='$TITLE'><text>filename</text></item>
</fileresource>